# change asp.net request/response encoding for one single page

Tags: asp.net, encoding

I have following settings in my web.config (unfortunately)

```
<globalization fileEncoding="Windows-1252" requestEncoding="Windows-1252" responseEncoding="Windows-1252" />
```

If I want to change one page's request encoding to UTF8, I could not just use `<%@ Page RequestEncoding="utf-8" ResponseEncoding="utf-8" %>` according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39d1w2xf(v=vs.100).aspx because these properties simply do not exist.

If I add code to my page's code behind

```
Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    Me.Request.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
End Sub
```

to force UTF8 as request encoding, it does not seem to work at all. But if I change web.config to use `<globalization requestEncoding="UTF-8" responseEncoding="UTF-8" />` then it works fine for this page. But I don't want to change the setting globally.

Anybody has some suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `location` section in `Web.config` file to set specific properties for just single page or folder. In your case you should add configuration similar to this:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <globalization fileEncoding="Windows-1252" requestEncoding="Windows-1252" responseEncoding="Windows-1252" />
    </system.web>
    <location path="yourfile.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
        </system.web>
    </location>
<configuration>
```

Comment: great solution, I almost forget the location.